# What is this inner product on differential forms?

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms

I am trying to understand the definition of $d^\ast$ of $d$ where $d$ denotes the exterior derivative as given in [these lecture notes](http://math.unice.fr/~hoering/hodge/hodge.pdf). (please see page 3)

Here are my thoughts so far:

Let us restrict for simplicity to $\mathbb R^n$.

Then the inner product on $\mathcal A^0 $ (=differential zero forms) is defined as (or so I understand):

$$ \langle f,g \rangle = \int_{\mathbb R^n}\int_{\mathbb R^n} |f(x) - g(x)|dx_i  d x_j$$

for some $i,j$ and $d^\ast$ is the unique linear map such that

$$ \langle df , g\rangle = \langle f, d^\ast g\rangle$$

But it doesn't work because one of the arguments is a zero form and one is a one form.

> What is it that I misunderstand?

My goal is to find $d^\ast$.

Comment: Note that there are two mistakes: Your inner product is not the same as that in the lecture note (actually the one you state here is not an inner product). Second. The domain of $d^*$ should be on one form $\alpha = \alpha_i dx^i$. So the defining equation for $d^*$ should be $\langle df, \alpha\rangle_1 = \langle f, d^*\alpha\rangle_0$.